# How to pass current record as parameter to a routine?

Tags: java, jooq

I am attempting to invoke a PL/SQL function via jOOQ using the routines. The function is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.default_sort(rec myschema.mytable)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE SQL
  IMMUTABLE
AS $$
  SELECT
      TO_CHAR($1.created_at, 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSSMS') ||  myschema.encode($1.id)
$$;
```

I am looking to be able to do the equivalent of the following:

```
SELECT 
    mt.*,
    myschema.default_sort(mt)
FROM
    myschema.mytable mt;
```

So in jOOQ, the routine is generated:

```
public static Field<String> defaultSort(MyTableRecord rec) {
//do stuff
}
```

But when it comes time to invoke, I do not know how to pass the current row in the the routine:

```
dsl.select(
        Tables.MYTABLE.asterisk(),
        Routines.defaultSort( /* What goes here? */)
    )
        .from(Tables.MYTABLE)
```

I can't find anything on the `Tables` or `dsl` object that suggests a current record. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.15, you cannot pass a `Field<TableRecord>` *expression* to a generated stored function reference yet, only a `TableRecord` *value*, which is constructed in the client. This would definitely be an interesting improvement in a near-future version of jOOQ. jOOQ 3.15 will start allowing to use ad-hoc `ROW` types as `SelectField` for projections: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11812

It would make sense to also offer this kind of functionality to `Table` types, which are nominal `ROW` types:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4727
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12069

In the meantime, as always when a vendor-specific feature is missing in jOOQ, you can resort to [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) and use:

```java
DSL.field("myschema.default_sort({0})", SQLDataType.VARCHAR, MYTABLE);
```